# Translation of faster than / slower than statement in algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen problems but not a detailed explanation how to exactly translate work problems in algebra that use the statements faster than or slower than.

For example, "Person A is faster than Person B by 30%. If A is the speed of person A and B is the speed of person B, personally I would create an equation B = (1 + 0.3)A. This is the style used in solutions I have seen involving these problems.

But my question is, why is it made in that particular way. I have seen wrong interpretations of the statement such as A = (1 - 0.3)B. Again, I have not seen any textbook or reference as of my searching that actually takes the time to carefully explain this particular topic.

Also, what would you do if it is slower? For example if A is 30% slower than B? Is it equivalent to B being 30% faster than A? Is the equation suppose to be represented as B = (1 - 0.3)A. Surely not, because if that would be the pattern then being 100% would result to B = (1 - 1)A which is definitely not the case.

I would also like to ask if there are any references that do discuss these particular types of statements, translations and problems. Thank you.

Note: I used my tablet to type this and I am not familiar with editing in LateX there so I was not able to put the equations in the proper manner.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, "Person A is faster than Person B by 30%. If A is the speed of person A and B is the speed of person B, personally I would create an equation B = (1 + 0.3)A.

If you use $s_a, s_b$ to represent the relative speeds of A and B, respectively, then the equation is

$$s_a = (1 + 0.3)s_b.$$

Alternatively, if you use $t_a, t_b$ to represent the relative times that A and B will take to complete the same task, respectively, then the equation is

$$\displaystyle t_a = \frac{t_b}{1 + 0.3}.$$

> Also, what would you do if it is slower? For example if A is 30% slower than B? Is it equivalent to B being 30% faster than A? Is the equation suppose to be represented as B = (1 - 0.3)A. Surely not, because if that would be the pattern then being 100% would result to B = (1 - 1)A which is definitely not the case.

I completely agree that interpreting the word-problem composer's intent is often problematic.  My personal (arguably subjective) *best guess*, re the above paragraph is that

A is 30% slower than B

represents

$s_a = (1 - 0.3)s_b$

and

B being 30% faster than A

represents

$s_b = (1 + 0.3)s_a.$